# Avoid if else statement in tuples and make loop faster

Tags: python, list, performance, if-statement

```
import string

a , b , c = string.ascii_lowercase , string.ascii_uppercase , string.digits

l1 = [ (i , a ,b , c ,) for i in range(100,1000000) ] #all

l2 = [ (i,) for i in range(150,340192) ] # used

x = [

    item for item in l1 if (item[0],) not in l2
]

print(len(x)) # it costs at least 50 seconds to run
```

**I’m looking to improve my code or make it faster.**

Comment: `x = [(i, a, b, c) for i in itertools.chain(range(100, 150), range(340192, 1000000))]`?

Comment: `x = [ (i , a ,b , c) for i in range(100,1000000) if i not in range(150,340192)]`

Comment: Remove the unnecessary duplication of `a`, `b` and `c`. These are all the same every time. Restructure your code to use them outside of `x` and `l1`. That saves you memory, instead of duplicating all those strings.

Comment: I hope this is just for illustrative purposes, otherwise that is such a wasteful code, like l2 is completely unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l2` is a list (a very large one at that) of singleton tuples and you check for membership. Since you're checking for membership, making it a set will be much more efficient.

```py
# construct a set from the range
s_l2 = set(range(150,340192))
# check for set membership
x = [item for item in l1 if item[0] not in s_l2]
```

Benchmark:

```
%timeit x = [item for item in l1 if (item[0],) not in l2]
# 6.55 s ± 326 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit r_l2 = range(150,340192); y = [item for item in l1 if item[0] not in r_l2]
# 415 ms ± 5.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit s_l2 = set(range(150,340192)); z = [item for item in l1 if item[0] not in s_l2]
# 382 ms ± 10.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple idea is to directly judge whether each element is in the `range` without generating `l2`:

```
>>> r = range(150, 340192)
>>> timeit(lambda: [item for item in [(i, a, b, c) for i in range(100,1000000)] if item[0] not in r], number=7)
1.5238849000015762
```

It can also be simplified directly by comparison:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: [item for item in [(i, a, b, c) for i in range(100,1000000)] if not 150 <= item[0] < 340192], number=7)
1.341257099993527
```

The simplest way is to build the target range in advance, and then generate the target list in once loop:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> timeit(lambda: [(i, a, b, c) for i in chain(range(100, 150), range(340192, 1000000))], number=7)
0.5550074999919161
```